# What is the name of the part between SELECT and FROM in a SQL query?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to find the right description for the parts of a query:

1. What is the name of the part between `SELECT` and `FROM`? If I only had some columns then I would call it "column identifiers". But if there are any function or subqueries this would be quite a bit more. Is "SELECT clause" a valid description?
2. Same thing for the `FROM` part. If I have only one table I would simply call it "table". But if there is a more complicated structure maybe using joins, etc. what would be the correct naming?

---

To make my questions more clear:

In Postgres I could use a JSON function, e.g. `json_array_elements` in both parts:

```
SELECT
    json_array_elements(my_json_column)
FROM
    my_table
```

or doing this

```
SELECT
    elem.*
FROM
    my_table,
    json_array_elements(my_json_column) AS elem
```

If I have to tell somebody that this function can be used within the `SELECT` clause or as part of the `FROM` clause which terms are more conventional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's usually called a "[select list](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-select-lists.html)", which contains "select list items".

The `FROM` clause contains a [list of table references](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM).

This is not specific to Postgres, by the way.

So, with respect to your use case you might say that `json_array_elements()` can be used both as an expression in the select list and as a table reference.

Comment: OK, sounds legit. How would you call the same for the FROM clause? Maybe if you would have to say something like: "You can use the function inside the FROM clause as part of a join..." or something like that? (see part 2 of my question :) )

Comment: @S-Man: I usually use "from list" for that

Comment: "FROM list" here, too.